# Create AGP 7.4.2 Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Im trying to create a Project with the Java 11 jdk -> I wont be able to use AGP 8.x

Since Android Studio creates an AGP 8.1.0 project on standard I tried downgrading the project but it always runs a ton of errors if I do so - so is there a way to create a project with an earlier version on standard?
Any help appreciated :)